# Этимология слов: смех, смятение

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Могут ли быть родственны эти слова?
Смятение - это замешательство, только эмоционально в более сильной форме.  Слово "смех" можно трансформировать в
"смешок", где прослеживается общая основа "меш". Или я ошибаюсь, - нет здесь ничего общего? Словари говорят о том, что слово "смех" происходит от "смеятися" с древней буквой "ять", ныне не существующей. Но откуда происходит данный глагол?

Comment: Ясно,что смех – общеславянское слово. Или вы копаете более глубоко и вам нужно индоевропейское?

Comment: Словари не дают информацию о происхождении слова смеяться. Хочется докапаться до сути. Например. Зализняк выстраивает такую схему по поводу происхождения слова "пироженое" : пироженое - пирог - пир - пить. Возможно есть какое-то древнее забытое слово, которое и здесь позволит проследить подобную закономерность.

Answer (score 1):

Это разные слова:

**Смятение**

Мутить, смущать, смута, смятение, мятеж (от др.-рус мясти) — всё это однокоренные слова с и.-е. корнем **menth** — взбалтывать, вертеть, крутить. О.-с. вариант  ***motiti***.

Др.-рус. **"мутити"** — волновать, смущать, тревожить; **мутъ, мутъвь** — смятение, волнение.

**Смех**

Слово "смех" известно в др.рус. языке с 11 века, глагол смѣятися (с буквой ять), Х — суффикс (сравнить: грешить — грех).

И.-е корень **(s)mei,** сравнить (англ.) ***smile*** — улыбка.

Материал взят из словаря П.Я. Черных.